# group the object in array by name

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
let obj = [
    {
        name: "a",
        quantity: 2
    },
    {
        name: "b",
        quantity: 4
    },
    {
        name: "c",
        quantity: 88
    }
]

let obj2 = [
    {
        name: "a",
        quantity: 2
    }
]
```

I want to group two object array but if object which has a same name already exists then merge.

For example, there are objects which name is "a" and I want to merge them together.

Output what I want is like

```
[
    {
        name: "a",
        quantity: 4
    },
    {
        name: "b",
        quantity: 4
    },
    {
        name: "c",
        quantity: 88
    }
]
```

The quantity of object which name is "a" is add together.
Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forEach()` for this.

```js
let obj = [
    {
        name: "a",
        quantity: 2
    },
    {
        name: "b",
        quantity: 4
    },
    {
        name: "c",
        quantity: 88
    }
]

let obj2 = [
    {
        name: "a",
        quantity: 2
    }
]

obj.forEach((element)=>{
obj2.forEach((e)=>{
  if(element.name == e.name){
  element.quantity = element.quantity+e.quantity
    }
  })
})

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thx for reply. Sir how about the case when those two array concatenated already?

Comment: In that case instead of using nested forEach in obj2 you replace in with obj. It will check for each object in obj if the name are same it will add the quantity.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let obj = [
    {
        name: "a",
        quantity: 2
    },
    {
        name: "b",
        quantity: 4
    },
    {
        name: "c",
        quantity: 88
    }
]

let obj2 = [
    {
        name: "a",
        quantity: 2
    }
]

let obj3 = [...obj, ...obj2];

let obj4 = obj3.reduce( (curr, ele) => {
  let exist = curr.filter( cur => cur.name == ele.name)
  if (exist.length) exist[0].quantity += ele.quantity
  else curr.push({...ele})
  return curr
}, [])

let obj5 = Object.values(
  obj3.reduce((res, {name, quantity}) => {
    let ele = res[name] ??= {name}
    ele['quantity'] = (ele['quantity'] ?? 0) + quantity
    return res
  }, {})
)
console.log(obj4, obj5)
```